# Как добавить пользователя в чат с помощью telegram бота? - Python3

Tags: telegram-bot

Подскажите, возможно ли это реализовать через сторонние библиотеки?

Comment: бот не имеет права добавлять пользователей

Answer (score 2):

Исходя из [ограничений](https://core.telegram.org/bots#4-how-are-bots-different-from-humans), накладываемых на бота:

> Bots can't initiate conversations with users. A user must either add
>   them to a group or send them a message first. People can use
>   telegram.me/ links or username search to find your bot.

Делаем вывод, что это невозможно, используя лишь Telegram Bot API. Однако это задача выполнима, но для этого придётся написать своего клиента Telegram в котором будет использоваться Telegram API, который непосредственно [позволяет](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.addChatUser) добавлять пользователей в чат.